# Use suggested method parameters in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code suggests the right parameters for well defined methods as you type them. Is there a way to take them over / insert them straight away? Doesn't feel right to write the parameters with their types by hand...

[image]

Comment: I also not found this possibility, but yeah this is good idea to autocomplete from d.ts files. I suggest to add this feature request to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like that exists for `javascript` & `typescript` files:

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```javascript
"typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I added this, it adds paranthesis, but does not autocomplete variables

Answer (score -1):

Now its finally working as expected, Visual Studio Code 1.63.0 implemented "Method Signature Completions": https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_method-signature-completions